# Formula to remove leading characters

Tags: excel

Is there a function that I can use to remove the first few characters from a cell?

Example

```
1 some text
23 some more text
```

I need to remove the numbers so that the cells read

```
some text
some more text
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) and [I downvoted because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and more good information at ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580203/how-to-remove-all-numbers-from-a-cell-with-a-function-or-regex

Comment: Furthermore, you title is very misleading as your desired output has nothing to do with removing leading characters. You need to be clear if you want to remove all numeric characters from your string, or only under certain conditions. Include your own attempt, and as per @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns his comment you will have to look at how to create a clear question, and edit your question accordingly to avoid this being closed for being too broad.

Comment: `=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1)`

Answer (score -1):

You can use LEFT, RIGHT and MID functions to slice bits of Text out of a cell, and LEN to find the number of characters in a cell. The FIND function will return the position of a specified bit of text within a cell. And you can use the & operator to join text together

So If A1 holds "some text 23 some more text" then the following formula in B1

```
=LEFT(A1,10)&RIGHT(A1,14)
```

would return "some text some more text"

If the numbers are randomly interspersed within the text however, then you will have to resort to VBA to remove them

Answer (score -1):

If you only need to remove numbers (as in *all* numbers) from a cell you can also repeatedly use SUBSTITUTE

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,""),1,""),2,""),3,""),4,""),5,""),6,""),7,""),8,""),9,"")
```

Though it would leave behind double spaces `"  "` in the end so you might want substitue those double spaces with single spaces. In the following it replaces it 5 times (assuming the text would be something like `some text 23 01 52 63 some more text`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,0,""),1,""),2,""),3,""),4,""),5,""),6,""),7,""),8,""),9,""),"  "," "),"  "," "),"  "," "),"  "," "),"  "," ")
```